# The term 'tsc' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, compiler-errors

I want to compile a ts file into a js file and I have installed node.js and typescript with "npm install -g typescript". but when I want to compile the file with tsc app.ts command, I get the following error :

```
tsc : The term 'tsc' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was 
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ tsc sandbox.ts
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (tsc:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I have tried adding the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\0.8.0.0`  to my environment variables, restarting cmd and vscode after adding to environment variables, reinstalling the typescript, or adding the tsconfig.json file to the project.

Comment: RTFM https://www.typescriptlang.org/download "Globally Installing TypeScript
"

Comment: I have tried that but it doesn't work.

Comment: Okay, then if you did `npm install --global typescript` already and that didn't change anything you may need to restart the shell, if that doesn't help you need the NPM global install directory to PATH

Comment: I included `C:\Users\"username"\AppData\Roaming\npm` to my system's PATH variable and restarted the shell and vscode, but the problem remains.

Comment: If you open the directory which has `tsc.cmd`(or `tsc.ps1`) inside, then does `tsc` work?

Comment: I apologize for the mistake. It turns out that I had added the wrong path to my system's PATH variables. However, I have corrected it and `C:\Users\"username"\AppData\Roaming\npm` now works properly. As a result, the tsc command can now be recognized globally. thanks for your help @Dimava

Answer (score 1):

There are following suggestion you can try:

1. start with try to run the tsc and node command in cmd prompt.
2. Then go into project directory and type npm install -g typescript
   (this command installs typescript globally on ur PC).

Once it gets installed try command:
tsc filename.ts
If it generates js file successfully u r good to go then.